# Jackson parser skipping blackslash

Tags: jackson

Please could anyone give a suggestion for my following issue with Jackson, that is occurring while parsing a JSON string. I am getting the exception when parsing the following JSON string that is valid according to both [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) and [jsonformatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com):

```
{
    "field1": 123333,
    "field2": {
        "field3": "value3",
        "field4": "url=apps.facebook.com&param1=33&param2={\"app"
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be with the backslash character ("{\") in the value of `field4` url key. If anyone has had this issue before please could you share your fix it.

I am using jackson 1.8.2. and testing this in 1.9.11. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, that {\"app"} this is a valid value for this parameter?

Comment: You failed to mention the exception, we can't provide you much help without it. Also, include the code you are using to perform the parse.